# Regex for currency - missing one condition

Tags: regex

I have a regex for currency:

```
^(?!\$.*\$$)\$?\s*(?:\d{1,4}|\d{0,4}\.\d{1,2})\s*\$?$
```

where all of those values (values between 0-9999.99) are accepted
$9999
0
999.99
9999
999.9
$9999
9999$
$9999.00
9999.9$
$ 4999.88
4999.88
4999.88
4999.88 $
4000.88
4000

what I am missing is to have also comma accepted after the first number if it is in thousands so:

$4,000.00
4,000 should be accepted
and 4,00.00 should not be accepted

any regex specialist here that could help me out? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just went ahead and rewrote your regex to something which seems more appropriate to me:

```
^(?!.*\$.*\$)(?:\$[ ]?)?(?:\d,\d{3}|\d{1,4})(?:\.\d{1,2})?(?:[ ]?\$)?$
```

### Demo

Comment: your use case does not work, I did not want to recreate it to a new "requirement", for example 999.9 does not work and it should. "$" At the end it is because for some nationalities as Europeans (myself) I write sometime 999$ because I read it for example as 999 DOLLARS and not DOLLARS 999. That is why the dollar symbol at the end.

Comment: @JohnLong Fair enough, if you need to support `9999$` then try my updated answer which now covers that requirement.

Comment: Thanks! However, still does not take 999.9 :-) and takes larger number than 9999.99

Comment: Sorry, missed that, it was deliberate.  For some reason, I thought you only wanted two full decimal places, or no decimal at all.  Answer updated again.

Comment: and takes larger number than 9999.99 :D

Comment: Did you try typing `999999.99` into the demo?  It works.